# Use python to delete shape key from mesh, not object, or get vertex position with armature deform without using object.to_mesh

Tags: python, scripting

When using: `me = ob.to_mesh(bpy.context.scene, False, 'PREVIEW')` with `bpy.data.meshes.remove(me)`, if the object has shape keys, the shape keys are duplicated and hang around in bpy.data.shape_keys. I either need a way to delete shape keys from bpy.data.shape_keys, or a way to vertex position with armature deforms without duplicated the shape keys on the mesh.

Thoughts?

Comment: I think it would be useful to either simplify the title or explain more in the question body what you mean about getting the vertex position with armature deform.

Comment: If I do bpy.context.object.data.vertices[0].co I get a vector representing the location of that vertex without modifier effects. I need that location with modifier effects. ob.to_mesh is the only way I know how to do that. When I do that on a mesh with shape keys, the shape keys keep getting duplicated until I run out of ram. I'm running a continuous simulation.